# AngularJS: if(obj) vs if(obj!==null & angular.isDefined(obj))

Tags: angularjs, if-statement

Which is better way to compare the definition of an object ?

`if(obj!==null & angular.isDefined(obj))` or `if(obj)` ?

Would love to know the use and abuse of both methods.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `if(obj)` will check if `obj` is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value. Whilst the other checks are more explicit. [isDefined](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L481) will do a `typeof value !== 'undefined'`. Whoever is doing your code reviews is spot on.

Comment: Aren't null and undefined treated as falsy in JS?

Comment: Yes they are (my original comment was wrong it checks for truthy values not falsy) the reason your code-reviewer said to avoid is that it will coerce the value into a fasly. Which could be good or bad depending on your use case, usually more so bad. What if `false` is a valid value but `undefined` isnt, both are falsy. Its a similar reason `===` is preferred over `==`.

Answer (score 1):

```
obj = false;// this will work with obj=0; too

if(obj!==null & angular.isDefined(obj)) {
    // GOING IN
}

if(obj){
   // NOT GOING IN
}
```

So : if you have no idea of the type of data you're testing and you need 0 and false to get in, use the angular.isDefined along with null check. Otherwise if you know what you're doing you may use if(obj) {} if it suits.